# Comment delete button not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem with my comments. I can insert them in the database my friend made and echo them in the right pages, but the delete part isn't working. 
People with an account can delete their own comments, and admins can delete any comment. But when i click on the delete button of a comment, i doesn't do anything and when i click again it deletes every comment in that page, can someone help? When I click a delete button, i want to delete that specific comment only, not all of them. Also, the key in the database is the date the comment was posted.

Here's comments.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cssfolder/comments.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans%22%3E">
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="comment">
<form method="post" action="">
<textarea name='message' class="area" id='message' placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea><br/>
<br>
<input type="submit" class="commentbutton" name="comment" value="Comment">
<br>
</form>
</div>
<div class="commentcontainer">
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Curacao');
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=id1552202_accounts', 'id1552202_thecouch', 'Fargo123');
    $url = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
 $link = parse_url($url)['path'];
    $path = ltrim($link, '/');
    try {
            $zoekfilm = $db->prepare("SELECT film_id FROM Reviews WHERE path = :path");
            $zoekfilm->bindParam("path", $path);
            $zoekfilm->execute();
            $film = $zoekfilm->fetch();
            } catch(PDOException $b){
            die("Error!: " . $b->getMessage());
            } 
    $hoeveel = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE film_id = :id ");
    $hoeveel->bindParam("id", $film[0]);
    $hoeveel->execute();
    $count = $hoeveel->rowCount();
    echo "<br><b>" . $count . " Comments</b><br><br>";
    if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
      if(empty($_POST['message'])){
            echo "There's no message";
          echo "<br>";
           echo "<br>";
        } else {
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggeduser'])){
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $datum = date('YmdHis');
        $username = $_SESSION['loggeduser'][0];     
    $nospam = $db->prepare(" SELECT comment FROM comments WHERE comment = :message AND film_id = :id");
            $nospam->bindParam("message", $message);
            $nospam->bindParam("id", $film[0]);
            $nospam->execute();
            if($nospam->rowCount() === 1){
                echo "No spam please";
            } else {
            try{
            $addcomment = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO comments(Usernames, film_id, comment, date) VALUES (:username, :id , :comment, :datum )");
            $addcomment->bindParam("username", $username);
            $addcomment->bindParam("id", $film[0]);
            $addcomment->bindParam("comment", $message);
            $addcomment->bindParam("datum", $datum);
                $addcomment->execute();
            } catch(PDOException $c){
            die("Error!: " . $c->getMessage());
            }
            }
        } else {
        header("Location: /signin.php");
    }
    }
    }
    try {
    $showcomments = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE film_id = :id ORDER BY date DESC");
        $showcomments->bindParam("id", $film[0]);
    $showcomments->execute();

        while($result = $showcomments->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            if(isset($_SESSION['admin'])){
            echo '<div class="commentdiv">';
   echo '<p><b>'.$result['Usernames'].'</b></p>';
    echo '<p class="tijd"><i><small>'. $result['date'] .'</small></i></p>';
   echo '<p> '.$result['comment'].'</p>';
                 echo '<br>';
            echo '<form method="post" action="">';
            echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete Comment" name="delete" class="commentbutton" style="width:200px;">';
             echo $result['date'];
            echo '<br>';
            echo '</form>';
                   $delete = $result['date'];
                            if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
                    $verwijderen = $db->prepare(" DELETE FROM comments WHERE comments.date = :datum LIMIT 1");
                    $verwijderen->bindParam("datum", $delete);
                                    $verwijderen->execute();
                                }
echo '</div>';
        } else if(isset($_SESSION['loggeduser'][0])) {
                        echo '<div class="commentdiv">';
   echo '<p><b>'.$result['Usernames'].'</b></p>';
    echo '<p class="tijd"><i><small>'. $result['date'] .'</small></i></p>';
   echo '<p> '.$result['comment'].'</p>';
        echo '<br>';
            echo '<form method="post" action="">';
            echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete Comment" name="delete" class="commentbutton" style="width:200px;">';

            echo '<br>';
            echo '</form>';
        echo '</div>';
                      $delete = $result['date'];
                                    if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
                    $verwijderen = $db->prepare(" DELETE FROM comments WHERE comments.date = :datum ");
                    $verwijderen->bindParam("datum", $delete);
                                    $verwijderen->execute();
                                }
        } else {
                        echo '<div class="commentdiv">';
   echo '<p><b>'.$result['Usernames'].'</b></p>';
    echo '<p class="tijd"><i><small>'. $result['date'] .'</small></i></p>';
   echo '<p> '.$result['comment'].'</p>';
echo '</div>';
        }
        }
} catch(PDOException $a){
            die("Error!: " . $a->getMessage());
    }
    ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The procedure is wrong. Put the delete query and its execution out of the loop.

Comment: where do I put the delete query then? It doesn nothing now

Answer (score 0):

The query deletes all the comments of the page because it's in the while loop and you don't give a unique ID to be sure you delete the right comment from the DB. So the query is repeated as long as the page has comments deleting all the comments for the given date.

The solution could be :

- Add a primary key to the `comments` table if it hasn't one yet,
- Add the value of the primary key to `value` attribute of the delete button,
- Put the delete query **after** the while loop,
- Use the primary key you fetched from the delete button to delete the right comment,
- Fix your code indentation (the most important).

The code would look like this :

```
// ...
echo '<button type="submit" value="'.$result['id_comment'].'" name="delete" class="commentbutton" style="width:200px;">'.$result['date'].'</button>';
// Then outside of the loop : 
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && !empty['delete']) {
    $verwijderen = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM comments WHERE id_comment = :id_comment");
    $verwijderen->bindParam("id_comment", $_POST['delete']); // note that the $_POST['delete'] value is now the id of the comment. 
    $verwijderen->execute();
}
```

This must give you the idea. Good luck. ; )

Comment: ok, but the key i have in my database is the date the comment was posted, so instead of $result['id_comment'] do I put $result['date']? Would it work the same way?

Comment: What's the date format ? It's better to use a unique ID. Why not add an auto increment primary key to the table ?

Comment: this is for a school project, if i had time to do that i would do it and i appreciate the answer but i don't have a lot of time really. So is there any way i could still do it but with the date instead of an id?

Comment: @luisalcantara It's really easy and fast to add a primary key on a existing table. After that, with the above answer, it will work as expected : `ALTER TABLE comments ADD COLUMN id_comment INT(10) UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;`

Comment: @luisalcantara Did you tried this solution ? If you use the date, the problem is : which entry the query will delete if there are multiple entry for the same date ? In other word, It could delete the wrong comment.